Interdependency Issue in Power Enable Circuits for Sensor and Modem Controlled by STM32L476RG
I have designed a power enable circuit to control the power supply to both a sensor and a modem, each with its own dedicated power enable circuit. The MCU used is the STM32L476RG, and the power enable circuits utilize transistors and MOSFETs. The control signals originate from the GPIO pins of the STM32, which toggle the power states of the respective circuits. The power source is a Saft LSH20 battery (U2). The Nominal voltage (at 2 mA, + 20°C) 3.6 V and can Up to 4 A.

The issue arises when attempting to turn off the power enable circuit for the sensor. Currently, the only workaround is to activate the power enable circuit for the modem simultaneously, which allows the system to function correctly. If the power enable circuit for the modem is not turned on together with the power enable circuit for the sensor, the device will hang after turning on the power enable circuit for the sensor. This indicates an unintended interdependency between the two power enable circuits.


Below are the GPIO settings that assigned to enable the respective circuit.


I may not have the expertise to perfect this power circuit yet, but I am committed to learning and improving my knowledge. Is my circuit correct? I'd really appreciate any guidance or expertise to help me sort this.
UPDATE
PC4 - EN_PPVCC
PC12 - EN_PWR_BG96

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does the system fail because both I2C lines become low?

Hi @Jens , I don't think I used I2C in GPIO configuration for respective pin assigned to enable power circuit. Both pins are configured as output pins to control transistors and MOSFETs that manage power to the sensor and modem.

a) please add the datasheets as links of all relevant transistors and the MCU for easier help. b) Which pins go to/come from the modem? Which pins to/from the sensor? c) PC11, MODEM_RST - I assume it goes to the modem, if it is high while the power is off, then most probably the modem chip is powered through the reset pin and its assumbly existing ESD protection input diode to VCC?

Why is the other IO pin push-pull with pull-down enabled (makes no sense) and the other IO pin an open-drain output with pull-up? Is there a reason why both are not push-pull outputs? Other than that, the schematics posted look fine - so the problem is in the parts of the schematic you did not post or in the software - we have no clue what your software does with the pins to unpowered modules. Also, have you not debugged where the program hangs to understand why it hangs at that point?

NTR1P02T1G (P-MOSFET) -
https://wmsc.lcsc.com/wmsc/upload/file/pdf/v2/lcsc/2210210230_onsemi-NTR1P02T1G_C129192.pdf
BC847ALT1G (NPN Transistor) - https://wmsc.lcsc.com/wmsc/upload/file/pdf/v2/lcsc/2210210200_onsemi-BC847ALT1G_C209752.pdf
SI2301 3A (P-MOSFET) - https://wmsc.lcsc.com/wmsc/upload/file/pdf/v2/lcsc/2201141730_KUU-SI2301-3A_C2944155.pdf
AO3400 (N-MOSFET) - https://wmsc.lcsc.com/wmsc/upload/file/pdf/v2/lcsc/2201121800_GOODWORK-AO3400_C2938367.pdf

Hi @BitLauncher , In the code, the modem reset pin will go high in specific situations, such as when the modem doesn't work properly. Otherwise, the pin remains low. Below is the pin assign:
PC4 - EN_PPVCC
PC12 - EN_PWR_BG96

Hi @Justme,
The mentioned GPIO has undergone various configurations, and the current setup is the only one that works for now. I will post the details for both the modem and sensor parts. The modem part simply powers up directly after the power enable circuit is activated. The sensor setup is similar.
For the debugging part, I will send the error details.

Thanks for datasheets and MODEM_RST explanation -> his is not the cause. I asked b) before, because despite the power is off for the modem/sensor, there are other pins connected between U1 and the modem/sensor (chip) - which ones? Can you measure their voltages? E. g. if SCK would be configured as push-pull and being high, it has e. g. 3.5V and the modem chip is fed in an input pin with 3.5V despite its power pin VDD is off (should be 0V). But the ESD protection diode of the modem's SCLK pin will turn on & feed ca. 3.0 V to the VDD.... this is perhaps too low & leads the modem to hanging...

Appendix to previous comment: I assume (mostly) every digital (and some analog) chips have always ESD protection diodes on all its inputs - e. g. like 4538 in page 3-366 on right below - see Fig. 1 "* ALL INPUTS ARE PROTECTED BY CMOS PROTECTION NETWORK" --> even if this chip's VDD is disconnected (like power switched off via MOSFET in your circuit), via a high level pin and these diodes - a chip could be powered up, perhaps not enough, that it works properly... it could hang...

If P-VCC is turned off, both I2C pullup resistors will no longer work as required for the I2C hardware and the driver code may wait infinite.
